# AI (Internal): Current Activity is null for event = 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Stop'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

This trace message is popping up all over our AppInsights instance. I don't know what is means, or what could be the cause. I'm happy to provide any details that can help debug.

Trace message

> AI (Internal): Current Activity is null for event = 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Stop'

Details for one of the trace items pictured below

- sdkVersion: dotnet:2.7.2-23439

Comment: it was a known issue .https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/1009

Comment: there are punch of  same issue created in azure releated repos.

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj do we have any solution or any valid reason? We can convenience our higher management. :) :)

Comment: .you can get support from microsoft support.they will help you with resolution or workaround.hope its helps